# Where to start with C#

Tags: c#

Im a pretty experienced programmer in PHP and mainly web languages but today i have decided i want to start to learn a new language!

Im only 21 and I feel as I will never make it in the programming industry without a great set of languages under my belt, So i decided to have a look at C#.

The reason I have chosen C# is because some C programmers have told me that C# is the best language to learn for desktop applications.

I think i need to get started with the Syntax / Structure of C#, What Development Environment to use, and other things that i might face along my new journey.

I hope somebody can guide me
Thanks.

Comment: What industry do you want to work in?  C# is great for (a) vertical line-of-business and in-house application development jobs (you probably already checked that), but (b) Java is also huge for jobs these days. In my city, on one site that I checked, there were 110 Java jobs, and 58 C# jobs. Check your local city job ads first!

Comment: All the answers here are great, so I won't post my own, but I just want to add one more thing: **write something in C#**. The only way to really learn the language is to learn by doing, so think of a small program you think you'll be able to write, and get to work. You'll learn a lot along the way. Unlike dynamic languages like PHP, this is the only effective way to learn C#, IMO.

Comment: Best of all... Java and C# are similar enough so that it's relatively easy to switch! Saying that, I'd learn Java before C#... simply because the Java community seems to be more traditional and "strict" than the C# crowd.

Comment: +1 for broadening your horizons in programming :)

Comment: @waren P, Im not targeting a particular industry but aiming to get a greater number of languages under my wing to drive me into all forms of work,i would like to start with Desktop applications as i have some good ideas within that context, @musicfreak, Thank you for that comment, @Gary, im extremely eager to get started in WIN32 Apps

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For IDE, you can use [Visual Studio Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-express-vs). And [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial.aspx)'s a nice set of tutorials.

Also do get your basic concepts straight about [.NET framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) and [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime).

Once you get the hang of it, Try out [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query). It is (arguably)the most wonderful feature of the framework. Find some good LINQ tutorials [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/introducinglinq1.aspx) and [here](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/CSharp3-4)

Although you explicitly mentioned Desktop applications, .NET FW is equally suitable for Web applications [4GuysfromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/) is my favorite ASP.NET resource.

For Dektop applications you might want to start with [WinForms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), but [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) is the technology of the future. So you are better off learning it if you want to be developing Desktop applications for windows.

Happy Learning!

Comment: +1 for beating me in posting a link to VC# Express.

Comment: That tutorial set may just be what I have been looking for thank you !

Comment: Most new developers will get hired to maintain/improve existing WinForms apps, I'm guessing, but WPF experience will likely be on the "things you need" list for hiring, too.

Comment: I wouldn't bother learning WinForms.  Go straight to WPF.

Comment: @kirk Broadhurst, What benefits does WPF Have over C#, Ive only done minor research into WPF and it seems to be a graphical interface. focusing on THE GUI Part of things, If it comes down to building a high end end system such as a lets say a Site Admin Application to manage one of my sites, will i come across any issues regarding the available libraries.

Comment: @RobertPitt - I hope I haven't confused you - WPF and WinForms are not independent of C#.  They are purely GUI related.  WPF stands for Windows Presentation Foundation and came out with .NET 3.0, while WinForms (Windows Forms) is the earlier equivalent.  They are focused on the same tasks but WPF has additional features.  WPF looks towards the future whilst WinForms looks to the past.

Answer (score 3):

Stuff you'll need for the beginning:

- [Visual Studio 2010 Express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/)
- Few evenings with coffee and [Beginner Developer Learning Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx)
- A nice book like [this one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-2008-Wrox-Guides/dp/0470191376/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1275331416&sr=8-1) (it might be a giant one, but I'm in love with it)
- Some more coffee
- A lot of patience with stuff that isn't in PHP (LINQ, delegates, generic types etc)
- Some nice idea to start actually developing and trying stuff out

Comment: +1 for the beginner dev learning center

Comment: Thanks alot guys, Witch will be the more suitable for me, The tutorials provided above or the Beginner Centre.

Comment: I'd recommend running through both. There might be great points in both of them and it won't cost you anything.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to learn is to have a problem to solve, and specifically I mean to do something that you DON'T know how to do, rather than something for which you already have the tools. I'd browse around on the net for some toy problems and try to build an app for it.

Eg. I only started on the way down OOP once I decided I needed a poker probability calculator. So basically I had to read a bunch of stuff about VB 6 as I went along. Classes, properties, methods, syntax... the web is great for that kind of thing.

I suppose what I mean is **Just Do IT**... (see what I did there? :) You'll screw things up, but learn loads more than any book can teach you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio for Learning it you can use MSDN that perfect for early learning is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Illustrated C# 2008](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599543) by Daniel Solis.  That's the book I used to learn how the C# *language* worked (Don't be fooled by "Illustrated" in the title: it's not so much a "beginner's" book as much as it uses good illustrations to teach the language).

You might consider following up with a book dedicated to Silverlight, Windows Presentation Foundation, or ASP.NET if you want to be able to apply what you learn in C# to an appropriate API.  I would recommend any book by Matthew MacDonald for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Learning the basics Pascal, Java, C# and even C is more or less the same...

Start with the studying material of any academic "Introduction to Computer Science" course,
try solving the assignments in a few different languages (to learn C# at a C-like level),
then move on the material from any academic "Object Oriented Programming" course to learn the rest of the basics.

After that is only a matter of experience and searching the MSDN help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already an experienced programmer learning C# is more a less an exercise in learning the .NET Framework.  The syntax should be easy enough for you to nail down pretty quickly, just by looking for a few tutorials.  The harder part will be learning the vast API available to you via the Framework.

I suggest finding a good book on C# (I've had good experience with Microsoft Press and I've heard good things about Wrox and O'Reilly).  Make sure it discusses classes, polymorphism (inheritance and interfaces), event based programming, LINQ and reflection.

I believe you'll also want to look at any books dealing specifically with ADO.NET and WPF.  The great thing about .NET is once you learn the .NET Framework API you can pretty much move between languages as needed.